# nslXMLHttpRequest.send failing when used in XPiNC

Tags: xpages, xpinc

I have an iNotes List view object which lists the documents I want, and the related REST components. In the "OnSelectEntry" method I have the following code.

```
var unid =  items[0]["@unid"];
var myUrl = "test.nsf/main.xsp/docPathInfo/unid/" + unid;

var h;

if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
    h = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {
    h = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

h.onreadystatechange=function() {
  if (h.readyState == 4 && h.status == 200) {
      var myObject = eval('(' + h.responseText + ')');

      var result = dojo.byId("#{id:inputText1}");
      result.value = myObject.field1 + " " + myObject.field2;

  }
}

h.open("GET",myUrl,false);
h.send();
```

This code works perfectly if the NSF is hosted on a server, but if I have it local it fails with the following:

```
uncaught exception: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nslXMLHttpRequest.send]" nsresult: "0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)" location: "JS frame :: http://127.0.0.1:50113/xsp/.ibmxspres/.mini/dojo/.en/@Wc&@Eab&@Eya&@lu.js :: anonymous ::
```

I need this to work on the client. Is this the correct way to make the call back on the client?

I have tried changing the ACL access as well but it doesn't appear to help. I've also tried a absolute URL instead of a relative one.

**[Update]**

I tried changing to a Dojo call instead as follows.

```
var x;
var myCallback = function(data, ioArgs)
{
 var myObject = eval('(' + data + ')');

  var result = dojo.byId("#{id:inputText1}");
  result.value = myObject.field1 + " " + myObject.field2;
}
dojo.xhr("Get", {
url: myUrl,
handleAs: "text",
timeout: 10000,
load: myCallback
});
```

When I run this code, it works fine on the server but when I run it on the client it doesn't work. I get the following message in the XPages.log file.

```
1/10/13 10:45 AM: Internal warning: Check access being called outside of a request
1/10/13 10:45 AM: Internal warning: Check access being called without a valid session/database
```

Comment: Have you tried using the dojo ajax functions instead?  Are you calling an XPage view ajax from a non-XPage?

Comment: I tried the Dojo call but that gets me a different error. I've updated the document.

Comment: I think I understand a little better now.  You have the nsf sitting locally and you're trying to make an ajax request to a different database on the same local machine?  This will not work unless you have a domino server running locally on your machine. Instead of making an ajax request maybe you can use ssjs to surface the data you need through an XPages partial refresh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK I am not sure about how you would do it using REST on the client, but you can make a XSP.partialRefreshGet() call and that should work.

So for your code you would do the following:

```
var partialRefreshOptions = { 
    "unid" : items[0]["@unid"]
};

// If you want to do any processing client side.
function partialRefreshOnComplete() {}
function partialRefreshOnStart() {};
function partialRefreshOnError() {};

// Make the call. 
XSP.partialRefreshGet("#{id:someDummyField}", {
    params : partialRefreshOptions,
    onStart : partialRefreshOnStart, 
    onError : partialRefreshOnError, 
    onComplete : partialRefreshOnComplete}
);
```

Then in your "someDummyField" set that to computed for display and have the code like this:

```
if(!param.isEmpty()){
    // Do something with the param.unid. Alternatively... 
    return param.unid;

}
```

For recommended reading on this there is the "**XPages Portable Command Guide**", Page 176.

Just to expand a little bit on this, you should use the XSP.partialRefreshGet() instead of XHR, as AJAX calls can corrupt the backend document if not done correctly. This is also documented in the same book.

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly. Also it makes life a bit easier for me, as I don't need to sanitize the eval() any more. I used the Data as computed instead of computed for display.